# How to correctly use python webbrowser with system service

Tags: python, browser, systemd

I have a service running a python script. In the script, I use webbrowser.open() to launch the default browser. It opens browser correctly when I just run the script.

When I add the script in ExecStart, everything works fine without any exception when system boots. However, it just doesn't open browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a variation of the FAQ ["Why do things work differently under `systemd`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).

In this case, `systemd` is not supplying the `DISPLAY` environment variable that is available in your CLI.

The value for `DISPLAY` is not always stable, and there may not always be a DISPLAY connect to.

A recommended alternate solution for launching GUI apps is to use your desktop environment's "autostart" feature to automatically launch something on login.